# Fix timezone/dateTime for all users on my website

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have a website for auctions. I would like to have a fixed timezone on my website set to GMT. The reason i want to do this is that when i changed my time on my machine to GMT + 5 . The time on my website has changed. This would result in different closing times of the auctions for different users.

This is what i currently have

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$time = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
echo $time;
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: `Europe/London` is not GMT

Comment: @jhpratt my problem is after i added some auction in my wbsite for 2 hours GMT but when someone has GMT+5 or more ... the auction remains open to him I want to set the time for everyone on GMT+0

Comment: @Evert my problem is after i added some auction in my wbsite for 2 hours GMT but when someone has GMT+5 or more ... the auction remains open to him I want to set the time for everyone on GMT+0

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my problem is after i added some auction in my wbsite for 2 hours GMT but when someone has GMT+5 or more ... the auction remains open to him I want to set the time for everyone on GMT+0

Comment: The timezone in PHP isn't affected by the users timezone settings, unless you explicitly change the timezone for that user. And you don't need to repeat your comment three times.